# How to rename Laravel Events when broadcasting to pusher?

Tags: laravel, websocket, pusher

When I am broadcasting events, I have to use the Laravel event names like:

```
this.pusherChannel.bind('App\\Events\\ServerCreated', function(message) {
   console.log(message.user);
});
```

Is there a way, that I can rename events?

Comment: if you want to rename events then change class name.If class name will change then namespace will change and event name will change

Comment: Is there a way to not touch the event name?

Comment: @naneri did You solve that?

Comment: @Misiu, unfortunately no :(

Comment: @naneri did you have any luck with it...?

Comment: @usama unfortunately, no :/

Comment: Thansk @naneri for update.

Answer (score 10):

In Event definition file try:

```
/**
 * The event's broadcast name.
 */
public function broadcastAs(): string
{
    return 'server.created';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

navigate to your event folder from app\envent and event ServerCreated in the class of  ServerCreated put the following code under the function of broadcastWith

```
  public function broadcastAs()
    {
      return 'my_custome_name';
    }
```

this function will return your desired name to your pusher broadcasting event